# Roots for equations with fractional powers, from a math paper my old school gave me.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

How do we find out how many real and complex roots an equation of the form $ax^k + bx^n + c = 0$ has where $k$ & $n$ are non-integers ($n$ is just $k-1$)?

Comment: First, show us your effort, then we can help you.